# Exception when deleting std::vector<unsigned char> from opencv imencode

Tags: opencv

Im new to opencv and c++, Im forced to lean c++ to use opencv on my delphi app. So im exporting this function from dll to convert a pointer to mat back to bytes after image processing. This is the function im using:

```
DllExport unsigned char* MatToBytes(cv::Mat *src, int &outLen)
{ 
    cv::Mat &matCvrt = *src;
    std::vector<unsigned char> *poutVet = new std::vector<unsigned char>();
    std::vector<unsigned char> &outVet = *poutVet;
    imencode(".png", matCvrt, outVet);
    outLen = outVet.size();
    unsigned char* outBytes;
    outBytes = new unsigned char[outVet.size()];
    std::copy(outVet.begin(), outVet.end(), outBytes);
    vector<unsigned char>().swap(outVet);
    return outBytes;
}
```

I already researched about it whole day now but couldnt find an answer. if I remove the code

```
vector<unsigned char>().swap(outVet);
```

it would work fine, but leaks memory. if I put it in the code, I get "Debug Assertion Failed!" Hope someone can help me out, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use pointers to `std::vector`. This class already manage memory allocation and deallocation:

```
DllExport unsigned char* MatToBytes(cv::Mat *src, int &outLen)
{ 
    std::vector<unsigned char> outVet;
    imencode(".png", *src, outVet);
    outLen = outVet.size();
    unsigned char* outBytes;
    outBytes = new unsigned char[outVet.size()];
    std::copy(outVet.begin(), outVet.end(), outBytes);
    return outBytes;
}
```

Comment: its actually because I was using visual studio 2012, and using vc11 libraries of opencv.

Comment: Though im using your code now, didnt know that theres no need to destroy std::vector myself, I can see now that memory leak is not present anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself, I tried it on visual studio 2010 and its working ok. I was using vc11 libraries of opencv, so now Ill just have to build opencv on visual studio 2012.